# JavaScript object being changed by HTML Page when it shouldn't be

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am using the Angular Framework to create a SPA.  What I am trying to do is when a user clicks on the cancel button of a form the data displayed should go back to its original state.  To do this I am using a JavaScript object that holds the original information and then using angular.copy() to copy the original information to $scope variable for display.

The code that is saving the information.

```
getInfo.getMoreInformation("/views/people/" + $scope.vendorguid +"/payroll-details").success(function(data, status, headers, config){


            dataOracle = data.data['oracle-user'];

            $scope.oracle = {};

            $scope.oracle = data.data['oracle-user'];   


    })
```

The code that handles the cancel button click

```
$scope.orcancel = function(){

    $scope.oracle = {};

    angular.copy(dataOracle, $scope.oracle);

}
```

What is happening is that when the user makes a change in the form on the HTML page, the variable dataOracle is being changed.  So when the copy is executed the new entered data is passed to $scope.oracle.  I have used the same process on other pages and it works as expected, but on this page it is not working properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I was using the same variable for both the display and then input fields.  After changing the variables, the issue went away.